# How do you generate lots of binary de Bruijn sequences (somewhat small, such as less than 100 bits)?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been learning about de Bruijn sequences recently. I looked at [this C library](http://debruijnsequence.org/db/code/greedy/greedy.c) on [Greedy algorithms](http://debruijnsequence.org/db/greedy), and took what I learned to make [this JavaScript version](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/a7a4eada56349839d798254d9fa17023), which tries to make as many de Bruijn sequences as possible. Then I implemented a quick "[iterate over de Bruijn sequences in JavaScript](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/275920/iterating-over-de-bruijn-sequences-in-javascript)" function. The latter generates about 3000 before it's start chugging, and after about 5000 (starting from zero uint and incrementing by 1) it starts to hang for larger $n$. The former generated these ($n = 6$), but I'm not sure they are entirely valid de Bruijn sequences.

```
0100000
1011111
0000100100
1111011011
011111100000
100000011111
0000001100001
0000010100010
0001000101000
0010000110000
1101111001111
1110111010111
1111101011101
1111110011110
000001000101010
111110111010101
00000111111011110
00001111110011100
00011111100011000
00111111000010000
11000000111101111
11100000011100111
11110000001100011
11111000000100001
0000001000011100010100011
0000001010001100001110001
0001000011000101000111000
1110111100111010111000111
1111110101110011110001110
1111110111100011101011100
0000001000101100001100100101
0000001001100001101000101001
0000010000110100010100100110
0000010010100010110000110010
0000100001100100101000101100
0000100010100100110000110100
1111011101011011001111001011
1111011110011011010111010011
1111101101011101001111001101
1111101111001011101011011001
1111110110011110010111010110
1111110111010011110011011010
0000001000101001001100001101100101101
0000010000110010010100010110100110110
1111101111001101101011101001011001001
1111110111010110110011110010011010010
000001111110000101111011100111010001100010
000001111110001101111011001110010000100110
000001111110011101111010000100011000101110
000011111100001001110011000110111101100100
000011111100011001110010000100110111101100
000111111000010001100010111101110011101000
111000000111101110011101000010001100010111
111100000011100110001101111011001000010011
111100000011110110001100111001000010011011
111110000001100010000101111011100111010001
111110000001110010000100110001101111011001
111110000001111010000100011000101110011101
0000001000011000101000111100100101100110100111
0000001000011010001010010011100011110010110011
0000001001010001011000011001101001110001111001
0000100001100010100011100100101100110100111100
1111011110011101011100011011010011001011000011
1111110110101110100111100110010110001110000110
1111110111100101110101101100011100001101001100
1111110111100111010111000011011010011001011000
000000100001100100101000101110001110100110101011
000000100010101100001100100101110001110100110101
000001000011000101000111010010011010101100101110
000001000101001001100001101010110010111000111010
111110111010110110011110010101001101000111000101
111110111100111010111000101101100101010011010001
111111011101010011110011011010001110001011001010
111111011110011011010111010001110001011001010100
000001111110000100011000101111011100111010110010011011010
000001111110000100111001100011011110110010111010001010010
000001111110001100111001000010011011110110100010111010110
000011111100001000110001011110111001110100110110010010100
111100000011110111001110100001000110001011001001101101011
111110000001110011000110111101100100001001011101000101001
111110000001111011000110011100100001001101000101110101101
111110000001111011100111010000100011000101001101100100101
000000100001100010100011100100101100110100111110101011101101111
000000100001100010100011101001001101010110010111100111110110111
000000100001100100101000101101001101110001110101011110011111011
000000100010100100110000110101011001011100011101101111001111101
000001000011000101000111001001011001101001111010101110110111110
111110111100111010111000110110100110010110000101010001001000001
111111011101011011001111001010100110100011100010010000110000010
111111011110011011010111010010110010001110001010100001100000100
111111011110011101011100010110110010101001101000011000001001000
111111011110011101011100011011010011001011000001010100010010000
0000001000011000101000111001001011001101001111010101110110111111
0000011111100001000110001011110111001110100110110010010101101010
1111100000011110111001110100001000110001011001001101101010010101
1111110111100111010111000110110100110010110000101010001001000000
```

That is, it only generated less than 100 for *all of $n = 6$*. There are probably thousands or millions, according to the [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A016031), so what I generated is pretty sparse.

What I for this last example is from the greedy C library. There are 4 greedy functions (min/max/same/opposite), which says how it processes the next bit. They also "seed" the functions with initial bits. All the papers I saw only have 1 seed, but I tried generating every possible seed (so all 5 or 6 bit numbers), and then running through every greedy function. But that's only 32 ($2^5$) times 4 sequences.

**How do you generate thousands or millions of de Bruijn sequences?** How do you iterate through them from the lower values to higher values? Don't have to write the specific algorithm necessarily, but how does it work generally? Should I be looking for alternative/more "functions" like these greedy functions, such as the "[shift rules](http://debruijnsequence.org/db/shift)" like PCR etc. from that site? Or must I generate/come up with my own functions? What is the plan here? How do I get more sequences efficiently?

*I am only looking for relatively small sequences, like less than 100 bits, nothing extremely large (which I presume is used in bioinformatics and other places. Mainly, I want to generate the leading/trailing zeroes de Bruijn tables, and know how it works in detail :).*

I checked out [*A framework for constructing de Bruijn sequences via simple successor rules by Gabric et al.*](http://www.cis.uoguelph.ca/%7Esawada/papers/DBframework.pdf) briefly, but after looking at the relevant C code, my understanding is that each of these functions can only produce **one** de Bruijn sequence for each $n$. Unless I missing something.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1377263/5266) says:

> For small $n$, a depth-first search using a list or set of "already seen" subsequences does the trick.

So is it possible? I am still not sure. [I tried implementing the depth-first search "eulerian cycle" stuff](https://gist.github.com/lancejpollard/27e145248b3baa2e6331d25b831241b8) from that Math SE link, but not getting the desired results yet.

Comment: Perhaps it will be easier to tackle the problem by reformulating it in graph-theoretic terms: list all Eulerian cycles in the de Bruijn graph.

Comment: you have been told the definition of deBruijn in your other question, surely you can check if those sequence you listed above are valid